# Cannot find resource on suspending subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I am not a developer. I am managing a team of developers and they are telling me this cant be done. However i am finding on here that it indeed can be done.

Our website that we are building is subscription based. I need a way to award free subscription time to an account.

For example:

User signs up on Jan 1 and pays the 7$ per month subscription.

Next billing date is Feb 1 but sometime in Jan we grant this user 1 free month.

We need to skip the Feb 1 bill date and resume billing on March 1 (with out back charging them for Feb)

Can anyone show me where on the paypal dev site i can find the info on this? I would greatly appreciate it! I have looked through the other posts but cant find a link.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I know, this can be done using PayPal API but it is not through recurring payment API. One way to do this is to use reference transaction API and charge the customer whenever your system indicates that it should. Links:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/

This particular implementation requires your system to use scheduler of some sort such as cron jobs or daemon process to charge the customer when needed. So the flow looks something like this:

1. Customer goes to your website/system to subscribe
2. Your system runs Billing Agreement API to obtain billing agreement with the customer. Your system receives billing agreement ID and store it into database for future charges
3. Your system would determine when to charge the customer and when to skip.
4. When the time came to charge the customer, use the billing agreement ID and include it in Reference Transaction API.

I am outlining the above as general guide but I hope you got the gist of it.